# Bash add result of API call to logfile using regex

Tags: regex, bash

I have raw data in this format:

```
[Wed Sep 01 15:37:10.709437 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 15732] [client [IP REDACTED]:56163] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/[REDACTED].com/html/wp-admin/admin-post.php
```

The API call looks like this:

```
curl 'https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=[REDACTED]&ip=[REDACTED]'
```

and the result of that is:

```
{"ip":"[REDACTED]","continent_code":"EU","continent_name":"Europe","country_code2":"DE","country_code3":"DEU","country_name":"Germany","country_capital":"Berlin","state_prov":"Bayern","district":"Oberbayern","city":"München","zipcode":"81549","latitude":"[REDACTED]","longitude":"[REDACTED]","is_eu":true,"calling_code":"+49","country_tld":".de","languages":"de","country_flag":"https://ipgeolocation.io/static/flags/de_64.png","geoname_id":"8772423","isp":"[REDACTED]","connection_type":"","organization":"[REDACTED]","currency":{"code":"EUR","name":"Euro","symbol":"€"},"time_zone":{"name":"Europe/Berlin","offset":1,"current_time":"2021-09-02 23:08:55.514+0200","current_time_unix":1630616935.514,"is_dst":true,"dst_savings":1}}
```

What I've got so far:

```
grep -P "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):[0-9]+\b" ~/Documents/hosting/web/logscript_results.txt
```

This matches any IPv4 address and the port number. I want the port to be replaced by the country_name of the corresponding address, e.g.:

```
[Wed Sep 01 15:37:10.709437 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 15732] [client [IP REDACTED]: Germany AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/[REDACTED].com/html/wp-admin/admin-post.php
```

How do I move forward from my regex?

Comment: Use `jq` or another JSON-aware tool to extract information from the curl output.

Comment: Let's assume I have that. How do I replace the port number by that information? How can I include an API call into a regex-search and in the same command use the result of that call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, if you are going to be working with JSON in bash and you are able to install packages on the system, you should absolutely get and use `jq`.

First, let's `grep` your raw data/logfile for the ip address and store it in a variable using command substitution. Here I am making use of your regex but adding the `-o` option to only capture the IP+port:

```
LOG_IP_PORT=$(grep -Po "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):[0-9]+\b" ~/Documents/hosting/web/logscript_results.txt)
```

Now, I assume that the ipgeolocation API only wants the IP address, not the port. Even if it can accept the port, it will be useful for us to have only the IP address stored in another variable. So we will use variable substitution to trim the string:

```
LOG_IP_ONLY=${LOG_IP_PORT/%:*}
```

Next, it's time to make the API call with curl, and use our `$LOG_IP_ONLY` variable in place of the IP address query field. Again, we'll store the result in a variable w/command substitution:

```
JSON_RESPONSE=$(curl "https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=[REDACTED]&ip=${LOG_IP_ONLY}")
# must use double-quotes ("), NOT single-quotes (')
```

Here's where `jq` comes in to parse the API response:

```
COUNTRY_NAME=$(jq -r '.country_name' <<< $JSON_RESPONSE)
# the -r option outputs only raw data without any quotation
```

However, if you must use `grep`/regex instead of `jq`, scratch that last line and use this:

```
COUNTRY_NAME=$(grep -Po '"country_name"\s*:\s*"\K([^"]*)' <<< $JSON_RESPONSE)
```

Now we have all of the necessary data, we just need to do the actual replacing in your logfile:

```
sed -i "s/${LOG_IP_PORT}/${LOG_IP_ONLY}:${COUNTRY_NAME}/g" ~/Documents/hosting/web/logscript_results.txt
# the -i option edits the input file in place
```

Putting it all together:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_IP_PORT=$(grep -Po "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):[0-9]+\b" ~/Documents/hosting/web/logscript_results.txt)
LOG_IP_ONLY=${LOG_IP_PORT/%:*}

JSON_RESPONSE=$(curl "https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=[REDACTED]&ip=${LOG_IP_ONLY}")

COUNTRY_NAME=$(jq -r '.country_name' <<< $JSON_RESPONSE)
# or:
# COUNTRY_NAME=$(grep -Po '"country_name"\s*:\s*"\K([^"]*)' <<< $JSON_RESPONSE)

sed -i "s/${LOG_IP_PORT}/${LOG_IP_ONLY}:${COUNTRY_NAME}/g" ~/Documents/hosting/web/logscript_results.txt
```

It is important to note that this will only work as-is if there is only one IP address  present in your logfile.

If you want to only apply this to the first IP address in the logfile you can use `head`, like so:

```
LOG_IP_PORT=$(grep -Po "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):[0-9]+\b" ~/Documents/hosting/web/logscript_results.txt | head -n 1)
```

And if you only want to apply this to the last IP address in your logfile, use `tail`:

```
LOG_IP_PORT=$(grep -Po "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):[0-9]+\b" ~/Documents/hosting/web/logscript_results.txt | tail -n 1)
```

If you want to apply this script to ALL ip addresses in the logfile, you will need to define an array of the IP addresses and loop through the array with `for`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort! I did what I wanted to do with a python script in the meantime but I surely learned a lot from your answer.